# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP TABLE PUBLIC.PRODUCTS-[*]USERS IF EXISTS "

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to write tests and using in memory DB. My problem is to create schema for tests from hibernate entities.

I have such entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "product")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "products_users",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")})
    private Set<Product> products;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Date createdOn;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "modified_on")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Date modifiedOn;

    public User(String name, Set<Product> products, Date createdOn, Date modifiedOn) {
        this.name = name;
        this.products = products;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "product", schema = "public")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Date createdOn;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "modified_on")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Date modifiedOn;

    public Product(String name, Date createdOn, Date modifiedOn) {
        this.name = name;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "products_users", schema = "public")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductsUsers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private UUID userId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private UUID productId;

}
```

and

> application.properties

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
server.port=8081
debug=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

And I have

> application.properties

in tests package

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

And I get such exception

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL "alter table "public"."products_users" drop constraint
>   "FK2w1ylwiyjuy67n1ycr5lv5or3"" via JDBC Statement
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   "products_users" not found; SQL statement: alter table
>   "public"."products_users" drop constraint
>   "FK2w1ylwiyjuy67n1ycr5lv5or3"

Comment: Well, "products-users" needs to be escaped. The SQL generation may have a bug regarding this, but if you're eager to continue developing, switch to the more classic and user friendly "products_users" name.

Comment: FWIW, you don't appear to be specifying a Hibernate dialect in the "tests" version of your application.properties.

Comment: @Kayaman, thanks, but then I have another exception, It seems that h2 doesn't see entities

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table products_users drop constraint FKs13160e0qfdn6jmmrte6q619q" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PRODUCTS_USERS" not found; SQL statement: alter table products_users drop constraint FKs13160e0qfdn6jmmrte6q619q [42102-199]

Comment: @GordThompson, it doesn't help

Comment: re: comment from @Kayaman - Hibernate also has a "globally quoted identifiers" (true/false) property that might help with object name escaping.

Comment: @GordThompson, now I have test application.properties like this
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public

and I have exceptions

chema "public" not found

Comment: Are you familiar with H2's [compatibility modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)?

Comment: @GordThompson, not very close. I add  MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE to properties file and I get exception that Table "products_users" not found

Comment: Why are you using `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` when you are using H2?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I believe that the intent is to use H2 (presumably in PostgreSQL compatibility mode) to mock a real PostgreSQL backend for testing.

Comment: @GordThompson That might work if you do not use Hibernate to generate the DDL, AFAIK. The OP might be better off using - for example - test-containers-java to get an actual PostgreSQL instance.